# Why would one player get the Fireside Friends achievement and not the other?

Tags: hearthstone

I had a couple of new Hearthstone players over. The three of us (2 on Android, one on PC) signed in, and the PC player and I played some challenge matches. After a few games, the PC player got the [Fireside Friends](http://www.hearthhead.com/achievement=113/fireside-friends#comments) achievement. I did not. I checked to verify that I didn't already have the card back. He hadn't played at all prior to this event. Why might I not have gotten the achievement when he did?

Comment: If your friend played against you and your other friend. he would have unlocked it before you. You have to play 2 matches against 2 different people. Are you sure this did not happen?

Comment: @ChaseC Yes, I'm sure. We started playing as soon as he finished the tutorials. Player 3 was still working on the tutorials. From what I've read (and from the experience of the player that actually got the achievement), you can play all matches against the same player; you just need to have a third person also logged in on the same subnet.

Comment: There's some weird logic with it. I know in my case, I played several games, but never got it. Turns out, I had to select my friend from the "on your local network" tab instead of from my friends tab, play the games, and then I got it. You'll have to fiddle with some stupid stuff.

Comment: Is it possible you can only get it on a PC version?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you played at least 3 games against a player on the same subnet with at least 3 of you logged into Hearthstone on the same subnet.

You may have to sign out of Battle.net and sign back in. [I know that some people said that swapping the device they play on worked out too](http://www.hearthhead.com/achievement=113/fireside-friends#comments). Try logging onto your friends PC and having 3 games on your account to see if it unlocks.